# Spring Batch - Is there a way create a Stored Procedure step which neither reads nor writes?

Tags: java, sql, spring-batch

I have a stored procedure that runs at the end of a chain of steps that merely merges the resulting data on the database itself. I have no need to read nor write any data as a result. Just a successful execution is enough.

Is there a simple way to do this?

My step looks something like this so far...

```
    <batch:step id="CleanupStep">
        <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager">
            <batch:chunk reader="MergeCleanup"
                         writer="NoOpWriter"/>
            <batch:transaction-attributes propagation="NEVER"/>
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>

<bean id="MergeCleanup"
      class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.StoredProcedureItemReader" scope="step">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="DataSource"/>
    <property name="procedureName" value="MERGE_CLEANUP"/>
</bean>
<bean id="NoOpWriter"
      class="my.package.NoOpWriter">
</bean>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a [TaskletStep](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/configureStep.html#taskletStep) is the right solution.
You can found many examples around the net.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that tasklets aren't transactional like the readers/writers. If you want transactions on your tasklet, you'll need to use @Transactional on the tasklet's `execute(...)` method.  This may or may not matter to you since your stored procedure may have the commit/rollback built in.

Comment: @IceBox13 is incorrect.  `Tasklets` are transactional and the `Tasklet#execute` method is executed in a transaction.  In fact, chunk based steps are really just a Tasklet step that executes the `ChunkOrientedTasklet`.

Comment: @MichaelMinella So in my experience, when I've implemented `Tasklet`, it did not rollback when an exception occurred.  This was only achieved when I added `@Transactional` to the `execute` method. So you're saying this should be default behavior, or is there something I need to set in my bean definition on on my `Tasklet` class itself?  My bean definition is a very simple one, like:  `@Bean public Step myTasklet(StepBuilderFactory sbf, Tasklet aTasklet) { return sbf.get("myTasklet").tasklet(aTasklet).build(); }`

Comment: @IceBox13, we should take this conversation elsewhere, but at a high level, Tasklets are transactional and the use of `@Transactional` within Spring Batch in general is discouraged.  Feel free to contact me offline or create a new question to discuss further.